# exposing c++ class (derived from abstract) in R with Rcpp modules

Tags: c++, rcpp, r-package, rcppeigen

I have a c++ class [`svol_leverage`](https://github.com/tbrown122387/pfR/blob/main/src/svol_leverage.h) that inherits from an abstract base class `BasePF` (actually that's a type alias for something messy coming from a specialized class template).

Using the Rcpp modules vignette and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54502041/1267833), I was able to use `.factory` to call methods of the base class in R:

```
install.packages("~/pfr_1.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
library(pfr)
mod <- new(BasePF, phi=.5, mu=.5, sigma=.5, rho=.5)
mod$getLogCondLike()
```

However, I need to expose more methods, and I've started having difficulty. Some base class methods don't have great signatures--their types aren't easily wrapped to R types.

For example, in `BasePF` there's a `filter()` method I need to call that accepts, among other things, `std::vector<>`s of `std::function<>`s, of ... I decide to write wrappers in the derived class: `svol_leverage::update`. This returns `void` and takes two `double`s. Simple.

*How would I update the `RCPP_MODULE` macro to expose this derived clas method, though? This isn't cutting it:

```
#include "svol_leverage.h" 



BasePF *newSvolLeverage(FLOATTYPE phi, FLOATTYPE mu, FLOATTYPE sigma, FLOATTYPE rho) {
  return new svol_leverage(phi, mu, sigma, rho);
}


// Expose the svol leverage model class
// Recall FLOATTYPE is defined in the header we're including above
RCPP_MODULE(svol_leverage_module){
  
  Rcpp::class_< BasePF >("BasePF")
  .factory<FLOATTYPE,FLOATTYPE,FLOATTYPE,FLOATTYPE>(newSvolLeverage)
  .method("getLogCondLike", &BasePF::getLogCondLike);
  
  Rcpp::class_<svol_leverage>("svol_leverage")
  .derives<BasePF>("BasePF")
  .method("update", &svol_leverage::update);
}
```

It `R CMD build`s fine, but when I go to call the `update()` method on my R object, I get this:

```
mod$update(.1, .1)
Error in envRefInferField(x, what, getClass(class(x)), selfEnv) : 
  ‘update’ is not a valid field or method name for reference class “Rcpp_BasePF”
```

I can get it available when I add `.constructor` to the Derived class, and then set up variables using the regular constructor (i.e. `mod <-  new(svol_leverage, phi=.5, mu=.5, sigma=.5, rho=.5)`. But these variables won't have access to the other method `mod$lastLogCondLike()`. So it's one or the other at the moment. How can I avoid this slicing behavior?

Comment: R only offers us a C language interface and hence simpler signatures, so there are limits to what can be done with code generation. Rcpp Methods never had inheritance, I thinkl. I use it in RcppCNPy just fine with _templated versions of one core function_ varying different metrics.  You may be able to work something out if you only expose the derived class to C.

Comment: What I have done in the past is to stick with a clean C++ side of things, and then add glue methods to instantiate (and tear down) as well as basic interfaces to the key functions.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel yeah I'll move in that direction